# Zend Framework 2 Redirect seems to work but nothing happens (no redirection)

Tags: redirect, zend-framework

I am a newbie using zf2 and I am following the tutorial with the Album controller. When an album is added, instead of redirection to /album/index, the browser stays on album/add (url) with a blank html page. Can you tell me what happens. I forgot a parameter somewhere? Does redirect really redirect? 
This is the code:

Controller album:

```
public function addAction() {
$form = new AlbumForm();
$form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()) {
  $album = new Album();
  $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
  $form->setData($request->getPost());

  if ($form->isValid()) {
    $album->exchangeArray($form->getData());
    $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);

    // Redirect to list of albums
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album',array('controller'=>'album', 'action'=>'index'));
  }
}
return array('form' => $form);
```

}

Route:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array( // album is the name of the route. Tout url localhost/album...
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/album[/][:action][/:id]', // ...matchera l'action correspondante dans le controlleur...
                'constraints' => array(               // ...index est l'action par defaut si pas d'action renseignée dans l'url
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!. This had nothing to see with ZF2. I had to re-install Wampserver for another reason and everything works fine now!!. But I do not know exactly why it failed.